# How to run python script inside virtualenv from PHP post

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, selenium

Hello im trying to run python script inside virtualenv from php but i cannot do it as well.

I wanna insert a Social network in my input php and i wanna get link in my php page

My php code and script python are in different folders

This is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <h1>Search Yahoo link</h1>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="text" name="social_network" placeholder="">
        <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Go">
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Search'])) {
        $item=$_POST['social_network'];
        #$tmp = exec("python php_python.py $item");         This line it works if python script isnt in Virtual environment (Outside)
        $tmp = exec("cd C:/Users/admin/Desktop/python venv\scripts\activate.bat python yahoo.py $item");
        echo $tmp;  
    } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, sys

social_network = int(sys.argv[1])       # will receive values like: Facebook, Instagram, twitter, etc

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://espanol.yahoo.com/?p=us')

#Search Social Network
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uh-search-box"]').send_keys(social_network)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uh-search-button"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="web"]/ol/li[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[1]').text
print(link)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not just use selenium for PHP? using exec you risk server security.

Comment: I know that i can use PHP selenium. but i already have many scripts in python. i cant go back

Comment: For one you're cd is into a bat file, not a folder. that's probably it.

Comment: Yes, i did it with bat file... and .bat activate virtualenv and execute my script python

Comment: you can't change directory into a bat file, change directory into the directory, run the batch, then execute the python script. Or even better just add the python line into the batch file and run it directly.